# How to prevent webapi endpoints for period of time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using web api/mvc 5 and trying to stop any further endpoints for a period.  Is it possible to do this for a global filter based on ActionFilterAttribute?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
{
    bool isSystemShutdown = _systemService.isSystemShutdownScheduled();
    if (isSystemShutdown == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return a response back. Set the `Response` property of filterContext to a valid response as you want.

Here i am returning a 200 OK . You can update it to return whatever you want ( custom data/message etc)

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
{
    bool isSystemShutdown = _systemService.isSystemShutdownScheduled();
    if (isSystemShutdown)
    {
        var r= new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        filterContext.Response = r;
        return;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Now you can register this globally in the `Application_Start` event of `global.asax.cs`

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new YourFilter());
```

If you want to specify a message back to the caller code, you can do that.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
{
    bool isSystemShutdown = _systemService.isSystemShutdownScheduled();
    if (isSystemShutdown)
    {
        var s = new { message = "System is down now" };
        var r= filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(s);
        filterContext.Response = r;
        return;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

This will return a JSON structure like below with 200 OK response code.

```
{"message":"System is down now"}
```

If you want to send a different response status code, you can set the `filterContext.Response.StatusCode` property value to an HttpStatus code as needed.